# Как делать правильно?

Tags: php

Так получилось, что мне нужно выводить посередине страницы результат работы функции в зависимости от значения переменной, которая принимает своё значение из $_GET, функция делает разное.

Например:

```
PHP код, ла ла ла
switch ($get) {   
    case 1:
        function GET() {
            ла ла ла
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        function GET() {
            ту ту ту
        }
        break;
    ... и т.д.
}
```

И выводится это всё примерно так:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <? GET(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Причём в функции иногда есть посылка заголовков (header), а как известно, посылать заголовки после того как уже был вывод в браузер - не рекомендуется. Ну так вот, вопрос - как вообще подобное сделать правильно? Когда PHP установлен как модуль Апача - заголовки отправляются с радостью, а когда как CGI - то спасает буферизация вывода.

P.S. Кстати, кто-нибудь знает, чего нужно бояться при использовании функции `ob_start()`? Она может создать нагрузку какую-нибудь серьёзную? Или другие проблемы? Переполнение буфера?

Comment: И выводится это всё примерно так:

    <html>
        <body>
            {function : some_function(some, function, variables)}
        </body>
    </html>

Вот когда выводится так, тогда круче! Поддержу ответ @razielsd и скажу что написать шаблонизатор не так сложно! Самому потом приятно отделить логику от представления!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function get1() {}
function get2() {}
function get3() {}
function get4() {}

// допустим $_GET['n'] всегда число

$method = 'get' . $_GET['n'];
if ( function_exists($method) ) {
  $method();
}
```

Comment: @exec Функция всегда называется одинаково. Просто в зависимости от значения переменной, кишочки функции меняются. :) Но всё равно спасибо, узнала что-то новое. :)

Comment: Передавайте необходимый параметр в аргумент функции, в функции создавайте необходимые условия.

Comment: @exec Наверное, у меня не получилось правильно задать вопрос. Сначала идёт логика, определение пользовательской функции, что именно делает функция - зависит от переменной, но это не имеет значения. Главное - что функция вызывается в скрипте уже тогда, когда был вывод в браузер, а ведь в самой функции используются заголовки. Получается, что заголовки пытаются отправиться после вывода. Мне интересно, как переконструировать логику так, чтобы сначала решалось что да как, все условия, все перенаправления, а затем результат внедрялся в середину html, который уже начал выводиться.

Comment: Используйте шаблонизатор.

Answer (score 5):

```
$getMethods = array(
   '1' => function(){},
   '2' => function(){},
   '3' => function(){}
   /* N => function(){} */
);

$requestGetMethod = $_GET['n'];
if(!empty( $getMethods[ $requestGetMethod ] )) {
    $getMethods[ $requestGetMethod ] ();
    // ..........
}
```

---

Уважаемые - вы издеваетесь что-ли? То, что вы не знаете что в php есть безымянные функции и того, что такая конструкция возможна и прекрасно работает - не моя проблема. Вы бы запустили бы сначала, а потом бы уже делали свои "гениальные" умозаключения.

Специально для тех, кто не в теме, (работает в php 5.3+)

```
  $hello = function(){ echo 'HelloWorld'; }
  $hello(); // -> HelloWorld
```

Как я понимаю вам обоим стоит уделить немного внимания вопросу безымянных функций в PHP, надеюсь теперь таких глупых вопросов и негодований больше не возникнет

Comment: @FLK, что очень жаль.

Comment: @AlexWindHope приношу свои извинения не на том сервере запустил (там 5.2). поэтому ошибочно сделал вывод что анонимные функции, отчего то, нельзя хранить в массиве.

Comment: Да я ничего не имею против, но одно дело не знать и, например, написать - у меня не работает и т.п., совсем другое пафосно заявить что это невозможно =)

Comment: Оуе......!

Comment: @AlexWindHope у меня 90% проектов работают на 5.2.17 поэтому "недопустимо" самое то слово. правда в ближайшую неделю обещают 5.4 поставить на хостинге где лежат 24 проекта. будет веселей )

Comment: Ключевые слова **у меня**, если так у вас, это не значит что так у всех

Comment: практически у всех, редко кто еще берет vps, денвер не в счет.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - причем тут vps?..

Comment: virtual private server, можно настраивать как душе угодно.

Comment: @FLK - я не писал что я не знаю что это такое, я не понимаю какое отношение vps имеет к вопрос безымянных функций в PHP. Или вы хотите сказать, что хостинг с поддержкой php 5.3+ редкость?

Answer (score 3):

ob_* функции прекрасно работают, и проблем с ними нету, на их основе работает множество шаблонизаторов, пользуйся.

Comment: @razielsd, спасибо. :) А точно? Я просто как представлю, что php сначала у себя где-то сохраняет вывод, а потом только выводит, кажется что это для него это тяжело и лучше не использовать лишний раз. У этого буфера же есть предел? Как узнать? Его же может не хватить?

Comment: Существенной разницы, на самом деле, нет, пользуйтесь так, как вам удобно